# python pyAutoGUI is giving an error that a file doesn't exist yet it does

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using pyAutoGUI to try and look for an image in a website.  I'm getting a particular error though and can't find any help on it online.

This is my code:

```
#locate an image on screen

import pyautogui
from PIL import Image


screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()

#pause between actions in seconds
pyautogui.PAUSE = .5

#swap to firefox at first run so we can look for the image
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')

# returns (left, top, width, height) of first place image is found  (863, 417, 70, 13)
deleteButton = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('/home/user/path/to/filename.png') 


print("location: ", str(deleteButton))

#come back to terminal to see if we worked or not
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
```

and this is the error:

```
$ python3 locateImageOnCcreen.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "locateImageOnCcreen.py", line 17, in <module>
    deleteButton = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('/home/user/path/to/filename.png') 
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 271, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 255, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 249, in _locateAll_python
    raise ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the image.')
pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image.
```

I can guarantee the path to the image is correct as I copy and pasted it from the command line and again from the file explorer to be super sure.

I've tried in python 2 and 3, same error.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Thank you

Comment: The error message isn't saying anything about the image *file*, it's saying that the image could not be found *on your screen*.

Comment: It's actually crashing though and causing an exception error beep on the OS.  It doesn't finish and get to the last ALT TAB or even the print statement.

Comment: Right, you need to catch the exception if you want your script to continue running in the absence of the image onscreen.

Comment: The try except thing did bypass it.  The command pyautogui.locateOnScreen retuns NONE if no image is found onscreen and the error I've shown is not a NONE response

Answer (score 0):

You must use two backslashes while trying to explain paths `\\`.

Example:

```
C:\\home\\user\\path\\to\\filename.png
```